# VBA identify the highest value

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

In theory the below program should read student's name and height, if an empty value is inserted to "Stud" the loop should end. Final goal is to display the name and height of the highest student. I used variable "K" to identify which value is the highest in the loop, but I run into dead end.
Unfortunately I stuck on following:

FIRST End the loop when empty "Stud" is inserted; SECOND Identify the name of the tallest student 
THIRD At the end create a table in MsgBox stating the name and hight of each student

Many thanks,

```
Sub C4()

Dim Stud As String
Dim High As Single
Dim cat As String
Dim k As Byte

        Stud = InputBox("Name")
        High = InputBox("Hight[cm]")

    Do While Stud <> ""

        k = High

        cat = cat & Stud & ("   ") & Str(High) & Chr(10)
        Stud = InputBox("Name")
        High = InputBox("Hight[cm]")
            If k > High Then
        High = k
            Else: High = High
        End If
    Loop

        MsgBox cat

End Sub
```

Comment: A user form seems more appropriate here IMO. Continuously spamming the user with a input box could get annoying.

Comment: First, `k` is a `Byte`, but you're comparing it to a `Single`. Decond, you end the loop with `High = k`, and start it with `k = High`. The line `Else: High = High` does absolutely nothing - it's the code equivalent to a truism. I also don't see where you're *using* `k` after the loop exits.  I'd start over from scratch. Collect all of the user input in a `Collection` or `Dictionary`, then process it ***after*** the user input loop exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a correction of your code with as fewer changes as possible so that you can understand what went wrong. I would also suggest to use a userform in this case:

```
Option Explicit

Sub C4()

Dim Stud As String
Dim High As Long
Dim TallestStudent As String
Dim cat As String
Dim k As Long

        Stud = InputBox("Name")
        High = InputBox("Height[cm]")
        cat = Stud & ("   ") & Str(High) & Chr(10)
        k = High
        TallestStudent = Stud

    Do While Stud <> ""

        Stud = InputBox("Name")

        If Stud = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        High = InputBox("Height[cm]")
            If k < High Then
                k = High
                TallestStudent = Stud
            End If

        cat = cat & Stud & ("   ") & Str(High) & Chr(10)

    Loop

        MsgBox cat & Chr(10) & "The Tallest Student was: " & TallestStudent

End Sub
```

So to make your three points work:
FIRST point: here you had to make sure you leave the loop right after no name is given (With Exit Do)
SECOND point: is done at the end. `High` was not clear in your code. Now it is the height of every student, and the new Dim `TallestStudent` gives the name of the tallest student.
THIRD point: Now the message returns the name and Height and the tallest student which was not in your code.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, helped me a lot. But I noticed 1 bug in this code. By placing 1st student outside the loop, programme cannot recognise who is the tallest in the group. e.g. if you run code with {Martin: 185 cm} {Jack: 160} {Sophia: 165} code won't recognise that Martin is the tallest student.

Comment: Right, then it is the same as in your previous mistake, You need to add the 'Talleststudent' variable with the first student too (see Edit).